# How can I register two database connections with nhibernate/lightcore?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, postgresql, nhibernate

I have to set up to the existing database(Ms Sql) another one(PostgreSql) with Fluent Nhibernate for my C# Mvc Applicaton. Someone know how can I register the postgreSql database in the LightCoreConfiguration (global.asax)?

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    RegisterDependencies();

    RegisterValidators();

}
private static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.DefaultControlledBy<HttpRequestLifecycle>();

// This is the current Ms Sql connection to the database that works and I have register here another connection to the postgreSql database
    builder.Register(c => NHConfiguration.CreateSessionFactory()).ControlledBy<SingletonLifecycle>();
    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).ControlledBy<HttpRequestLifecycle>();

    LightCoreConfiguration.RegisterGlobalDependencies(builder);
    _container = builder.Build();

}
```

**NHConfiguration.cs**

```
public static class NHConfiguration
    {

        private static FluentConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                           .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                                       .ConnectionString(SessionFacade.DatabaseConnectionString)
                                                       .ShowSql())
                           .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                                           .AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
                                           .AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomEntity>()
                                           .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>())
                           .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>()
                                        .UseQueryCache()
                                        .UseSecondLevelCache());
        }

        private static FluentConfiguration CreatePostgresConfiguration()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                           .Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(SessionFacade.DatabasePostgresConnectionString).ShowSql())
                           .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                                           .AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>()
                                           .AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomEntity>()
                                           .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>()
                                           .Conventions.Add(new IdentityConvention()))
                           .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>()
                                        .UseQueryCache()
                                        .UseSecondLevelCache());
        }

        public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return CreateConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        public static ISessionFactory CreatePostgresSessionFactory()
        {
            return CreatePostgresConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

I have already tried to setup the database connection without lightcore (and close the session after the application finished the request), but then an error was thrown that the connection was already closed, so i guess i have to register the session with lightcore.

Answer (score 0):

I found now the solution so that two databases can be used and where you can decide for each entity itself, which database should be used:

**Global.asax**

```
private static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.DefaultControlledBy<HttpRequestLifecycle>();

    SessionFacade.DatabaseSessionFactories[DbConnectionSessionType.MsqlSession] = NHConfiguration.CreateSessionFactory();
    SessionFacade.DatabaseSessionFactories[DbConnectionSessionType.PostgresqlSession] = NHConfiguration.CreatePostgresSessionFactory();

    builder.Register(c => c.ResolveAll<IDatabaseSessions>()).ControlledBy<HttpRequestLifecycle>();

    LightCoreConfiguration.RegisterGlobalDependencies(builder);

    // Build the container.
    _container = builder.Build();
}
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var sessions = _container.Resolve<IDatabaseSessions>();

            sessions.MssqlSession.Close();
            sessions.MssqlSession.Dispose();

            sessions.PostgresqlSession.Close();
            sessions.PostgresqlSession.Dispose();
}
```

**SessionFacade.cs**

```
public static class SessionFacade
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the database connection string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string DatabaseConnectionString => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Database:Connection");

    public static string DatabasePostgresConnectionString => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabasePostgres:Connection");

    public static Dictionary<DbConnectionSessionType, ISessionFactory> DatabaseSessionFactories
    {
        set; get;
    } = new Dictionary<DbConnectionSessionType, ISessionFactory>() {
        {
            DbConnectionSessionType.MsqlSession,
            null
        },
        {
            DbConnectionSessionType.PostgresqlSession,
            null
        }
    };
}
```

**IDatabaseSessions**

```
public interface IDatabaseSessions
{
    ISession MssqlSession { get; set; }
    ISession PostgresqlSession { get; set; }
}
```

**LightCoreConfiguration**

```
public static class LightCoreConfiguration
    {

        public static void RegisterGlobalDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
builder.Register<IDatabaseSessions, DatabaseSessions>();
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSessions**

```
public class DatabaseSessions: IDatabaseSessions
{
    public DatabaseSessions()
    {
        MssqlSession = SessionFacade.DatabaseSessionFactories[DbConnectionSessionType.MsqlSession].OpenSession();
        PostgresqlSession = SessionFacade.DatabaseSessionFactories[DbConnectionSessionType.PostgresqlSession].OpenSession();
    }

    public ISession MssqlSession { get; set; }
    public ISession PostgresqlSession { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    public Repository(IDatabaseSessions databaseSessions, DbConnectionSessionType connectionType = DbConnectionSessionType.PostgresqlSession)
            {
                if(connectionType == DbConnectionSessionType.MsqlSession) _session = databaseSessions.MssqlSession;
                if(connectionType == DbConnectionSessionType.PostgresqlSession) _session = databaseSessions.PostgresqlSession;
            }
    }
}
```

**Finally the service**

```
public class UserService
    {
        public UserService(IDatabaseSessions databaseSessions) : base(new Repository<User>(databaseSessions))
        {
        }
}
```